# Poor documentation for WayPoints

Tags: here-api, code-documentation

The documentation for waypoints is not matching the actual allowed API calls.  It can be found at https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html
Specifically, from this you should be able to use 
`geo!passThrough!y,x...`

but it only allows 
`passThrough!y,x...`

I have not tested, but this also implies using passThrough points will not work with the non geo waypoint types (links, streets).

Either fix the API or the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The below example where we use geo!passThrough works perfectly.

```
https://tce.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;car&waypoint0=40.7439905%2C-74.0323626&waypoint1=geo!passThrough!40.7127837%2C-74.0059413&waypoint2=40.7362318,-74.0350735&tollVehicleType=13&commercial=1&currency=USD&cost_optimize=0&app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyyy
```